# C++ 2D array indexing with 1 parameter (Why does this work?)

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, multidimensional-array

So I've been overloading an operator `()` for a 2d array class. For random tests I was doing, return was set to `array[0][index]`. Now passing just the index (row) with column set to 0. If the index is less than row (then we're in the next row) it still returns the data as if I had specified the column?

**Basic** code sample:

```
class myArr
{
private:
    float array[3][3];
public:
    myArr::myArr(float a1, float a2, ... ) { array[0][0] = a1; array[0][1] = a2; ... }
    // ^ the "..." just means, the same action till float a9/array[2][2] = a9;
    float& operator() (unsigned index) { return array[0][index]; }
    const float operator() (unsigned index) const { return array[0][index]; }
};

int main()
{
    myArr test(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
    std::cout << myArr(4) << std::endl; // Displays 5
    myArr(4) = 0; // Set's element 4 to hold value 0
    return 0;
}
```

Strangely this works. I can set/get the 5th element with 1 parameter. Now I want to know why/how that exactly works, surely it should error up with "out of bounds" or something. And finally would this be "safe" or do you strongly suggested not doing this?

*I rarely use 2D arrays, mostly due to the lack of performance gain from them.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array is stored in memory contiguously. In C++, multidimensional arrays are stored row-by-row right after each other in memory, so I believe it's a perfectly valid memory to reach beyond the currently row into the next row. Out of bounds would occur if you reached beyond the last row of your 2D array.

Whether or not this is a nice thing to do is a different question. Clearly, writing code this way results in readers scratching their heads trying to figure out what you're doing, so you want to avoid writing real code this way.

If you're declaring a 2D array, then you'd want to keep those semantics throughout the life of the array, so I would strongly suggest not doing this.

Comment: @user3046336 in cases of extreme optimization it might be faster to do 1D access rather than 2D. Except for that case your conclusion to avoid it is good.

Comment: It's debatable whether it causes undefined behaviour to access past the end of an array like this (altho I can't find the relevant threads just now)

Answer (score 0):

When you allocate a 2d array, its memory is contiguous. So if you allocate a 3*3 array of floats, you will allocate 9*4 consecutive bytes.
This results in:

```
&array[0][i] = array + 0*3 + i = array + i = array[i]
```

So "by chance", you get the right result.

Comment: More specifically, you're allocating nine array elements, each element occupying four bytes in your example assuming sizeof(float) == 4.